# INSERT Failed. 3800: Datatype Mismatch in THEN/ELSE expression

Tags: sql, case, teradatasql

INSERT Failed. 3800:  Datatype Mismatch in THEN/ELSE expression.  i'm facing this error in SQL tera data

Comment: A case expression's all return values must have compatible data types.

Comment: insert into dp_stg2.UnitMeasure_production
select distinct
case when UnitMeasureCode='NULL' then 'n/a' else cast(UnitMeasureCode as char(3) ) end as UnitMeasureCode,
case when Name='NULL' then 'n/a' else cast (name as varchar(50)) end as Name,
case when ModifiedDate='NULL' then 'n/a' else cast (ModifiedDate as date format'yyyy-mm-dd') end as ModifiedDate
from dp_stg1.UnitMeasure_Production;

Comment: this is the code

Comment: Hey, edit your question instead.

Comment: You shouldn't store the string `'NULL'`, store `NULL`, and the you can do `COALESCE(UnitMeasureCode, 'N/A')`. (If UnitMeasureCode is a character column.)

Answer (score 0):

You have the issue with your last `case` expression, both the valies (`then` and `else`) must be of same data type:

```
case
  when ModifiedDate='NULL' 
  then 'n/a' -- this is char
  else cast (ModifiedDate as date format'yyyy-mm-dd') -- this is date
end as ModifiedDate
```

You should think about replacing `n/a` with some valid date or null.

Comment: like could you please give me an example

Comment: Like current date or null or as per your business requirement but not char value 'n/a'

Comment: can i put getdate() in it

Comment: You can use current_date or null